# rosjava & Gazebo: Problem with sim time?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've ran into a problem trying to connect a rosjava node to gazebo running [turtlesim](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator). If /use_sim_time is true, rosjava crashes while trying to instantiate the logger:

```
Loading node class: de.se.rosjava.Main
May 20, 2012 1:05:38 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar <init>
INFO: MasterXmlRpcEndpoint URI: http://localhost:11311
May 20, 2012 1:05:38 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar onPublisherAdded
INFO: Registering publisher: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</TurtleSimJava/Main, http://127.0.0.1:36053/>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
May 20, 2012 1:05:39 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar callMaster
INFO: Response<Success, Registered [/TurtleSimJava/Main] as publisher of [/rosout], [http://ubuntu:45371/]>
May 20, 2012 1:05:39 PM org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultPublisher$1 onMasterRegistrationSuccess
INFO: Publisher registered: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</TurtleSimJava/Main, http://127.0.0.1:36053/>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
May 20, 2012 1:05:39 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar onSubscriberAdded
INFO: Registering subscriber: Subscriber<Topic<TopicIdentifier</clock>, TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Clock, a9c97c1d230cfc112e270351a944ee47>>>
May 20, 2012 1:05:39 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar callMaster
INFO: Response<Success, Subscribed to [/clock], [http://ubuntu:52317/]>
May 20, 2012 1:05:39 PM org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultSubscriber$1 onMasterRegistrationSuccess
INFO: Subscriber registered: Subscriber<Topic<TopicIdentifier</clock>, TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Clock, a9c97c1d230cfc112e270351a944ee47>>>
May 20, 2012 1:05:39 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: 
>>> Starting...

INFO: Subscriber registered: Subscriber<Topic<TopicIdentifier</clock>, 
TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Clock, a9c97c1d230cfc112e270351a944ee47>>> 
May 20, 2012 12:43:28 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info

Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-9" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
  com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:187) at 
  org.ros.time.ClockTopicTimeProvider.getCurrentTime(ClockTopicTimeProvider.java:58) at 
  org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode.getCurrentTime(DefaultNode.java:377) at 
  org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger.publish(RosoutLogger.java:58) at
  org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger.info(RosoutLogger.java:134) at 
  de.se.rosjava.Main.onStart(Main.java:28) at 
  org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$5.run(DefaultNode.java:511) at 
  org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$5.run(DefaultNode.java:508) at 
  org.ros.concurrent.ListenerCollection$1.run(ListenerCollection.java:117) at 
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) at 
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) at 
  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) ^C
```

If /use_sim_time is set to false, the node stops at ">>> Starting..." and seems to wait indefinitely (at least >= 10 min).

Did I miss something regarding rosjava and simulation / simulated time?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Andreas

P.S: The node causing this behaviour is

```
public class Main extends AbstractNodeMain {  
  Log log;  
  private Publisher<geometry_msgs.Twist> publisher;  
   
  @Override
  public void onStart(ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
    log = connectedNode.getLog();
    log.info("\n>>> Starting...\n");       

    publisher = connectedNode.newPublisher("cmd_vel", geometry_msgs.Twist._TYPE);        
    publisher.publish(createForwardTwist(1.0));
  }
  //...
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34373/rosjava-&-gazebo:-problem-with-sim-time?/) by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is bug in the sim_time implementation. See http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=115

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0